# Don't echo things with certain characters

Tags: php

I have a php program that looks at a log file and prints it to a page (code below).  I don't want the user of said website to be able to look at any line containing a `/`.  I know I could use trim to delete certain characters, but is there a way to delete the entire line?  For example, I want to keep something like "Hello" and delete something like `/xx.xx.xx.xx connected`. All the lines I wish to delete have the same common key, `/`.  Peoples names in said log file have `<>`s around them, so I must use `htmlspecialcharacters`

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/log', true);
$file = htmlspecialchars($file);
echo nl2br($file);
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: 
Thanks for all of the answers, currently tinkering with them!

EDIT2:
final code:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/log', true);
// Separate by line
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '/') === false) {
        $line = htmlspecialchars($line . "\n");
        echo nl2br($line);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: GOogle regular expressions.....that should get you started

Comment: currently you're doubling the string use `=` instead of `.=`

Comment: Late to the party, but there's no reason to first put in `\n` and then immediately turn it into `<br>`. Just do `htmlspecialchars( $line ).'<br>'` in the first place and drop the `nl2br()`. Since you're reading one line at a time it's guaranteed that there are no other line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean, like this?

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/log', true);

// Separate by line
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '/') === false) {
        // If the line doesn't contain a "/", echo it
        echo $line . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

For anyone wondering, [PHP_EOL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) is the [PHP](http://www.php.net) constant for "end of line" and promotes consistency between different systems (Windows, UNIX, etc.).

Comment: Nice touch with the `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` as in other answers.

Comment: I think it needs to be like if (!strpos($line, '/'), right?  Right now it ONLY prints the lines with /s in it

Comment: @Leetfail Sorry, yes. It has to be `=== false`, not `!== false`. My mistake :)

Comment: The `===` is important because `strpos()` may return `0` if the character is first in the string. The `0` gets casted to `false` when used in a non-strict comparison (`==`, `!=` or `!$foo`)

Comment: Also, the PHP_EOL Doesn't print new lines, is there another command I need to run for that?  nl2br seems to cause an error

Comment: Strange. Try `echo $line . "\n";` instead.

Comment: Nice touch. I've used PHP_EOL before, but it didn't cross my mind this time. Wonderful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str_replace` function - 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php. Alternate solution (*before escaping the special characters*) -

```
/* pattern /\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\sconnected/ = /xx.xx.xx.xx connected */
/* pattern will be replaced with "newtext" */
$file = file_get_contents("/path/to/log", true);
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
foreach ($lines as $line)
  $correctline = preg_replace( '/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\sconnected/', 'newtext', $line );
  echo $correctline;
}
```

Comment: The entire thing is one string, so if I find a string that contains these things, how will I tell it to just replace that one line with ""?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that pattern isn't significant for OP: "I don't want the user of said website to be able to look at any line containing a `/`". So using a regular expression is probably overkill here.

Comment: For now, I've only provided a solution for this particular pattern - `/xx.xx.xx.xx connected`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating through the file line by line you can check with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if the line contains `/`character and skip the echo if it does. If not, first split them at new line and iterate over that array.

If you don't want to split the file you can probably use `preg_replace` with a regexp such as `(^|\n).*/.*(\n|$)` and replace with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents("/path/to/log", true);
    $lines = explode("\n", $file);
    foreach ($lines AS $num => $line)
    {
        if ( strpos($line, "/") === false ) // Line doesn't contain "/"
        {
            echo htmlspecialchars($line) . "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Won't `strpos` return `0` if the `/` is the first char? I'd change the condition to `strpos($line, "/") !== false`.